# Short Channel MOSFET model

Tags: mosfet, cmos, semiconductors, fet, solid-state-devices

I was reading on a book (Thomas Lee, The Design of CMOS Radio Frequency Integrated Circuits) that in a short channel model, since the phenomenon of drift speed saturation is very relevant, it is a mistake to use the classical formula of the drain current of a long channel MOSFET, i.e. this one (we are supposing a MOSFET in pinch - off region):

[image]

It states that in a short channel MOSFET the correct expression becomes this one:

[image]

Then it states that, if VGS - VT is not so high, we may anyway use the first formula; if VGS - VT is quite high, we have to use the second one. I do not understand this last statement: in fact the difference between the two MOSFET is their length, and this determines that, with the same VDS applied, there is a high electric field in a short channel Mosfet (and so, speed saturation) and low electric field in a long channel Mosfet (and so, no speed saturation). Why should the choice of the model depend on VGS - VT?

Comment: What would you answer to the reverse question: why would the same model be valid for the complete range of Vgs - Vt ? Also note that there are MOSFET models for **triode mode** and **weak inversion** as well. For example the weak inversion models are valid when Vgs is close to Vt so when Vgs - Vt is near zero.

Comment: If I recall rightly, at about 2 volts per micron, the FETs move into "drift speed saturation" and the exponent becomes ONE. Thus 0.25 micron technology FETs will leave the square-law mode at a mere 0.5 volt across the source-drain. Does this make sense?